# Suitable API for using IoT devices?

Tags: ios, iot, opendata

I am writing an iOS app and want to be able to connect to IoT devices (get data from them). I want to be able to search an area for IoT devices I can connect to; (whether they be weather stations, seismographs, etc) (and potentially filter out devices of some sought if possible).

Is there an API which offers this? (finding IoT devices in an area), if not, is there another fairly straight forward way I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to simply "search for IoT devices". I'm afraid that you might have a misunderstanding of IoT devices are and how they exchange data. They can send data via bluetooth, wifi, etc. so not knowing what listen to is your first challenge. Second challenge is that even if you could see all of them and lets say but some super natural force you can connect to them, you'd have no idea the format of the data. A seismograph could be pumping out data that looks just like a weather station data.